# Curl, ping hangs/waits when using private network ips

Tags: vpn, curl, ping

I have a whole bunch of servers working inside my office premises private network. When I try to run my tests outside office network, `curl`/`ping`/`python`/`nodejs` requests library, all of them wait infinitely trying to connect to these private servers. This makes it impossible for me to run the tests outside office.

One ugly fix for the infinite wait is to bring down the internet and run it. But that is not okay to me.

Why do curl/ping not come out gracefully with an error code such as `404`/`host not reachable` message in these scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, if you don't want to modify your tests, is to use iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j REJECT
```

That won't work for ping, but it will work for CURL and some other programmes.

WARNING: Ensure you don't create a firewall rule that block your own network!!!!

Comment: this looks like a good solution since i use python's request library...  can you give the command that will undo this, just in case i want to reset all? will `iptables flush` delete this rule?

Comment: Flush will remove all rules. To remove only the rule above: iptables -D OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j REJECT